# How I can take a part of a string from a some position? in PHP

Tags: php, string

I have a simple question:

if I have this string like:

```
$mystring="|10|20|30|40";
```

how I can get the number 30 from $mystring?

I would like to use "|" for a separator, I know the number of the tokenat (2), but I didn't find any code for how to take a specific part of a text from the "|", and start from a specific tokenat (the second in this case)

and if I use a parameter "1", will get 20

someone has any idea?

Thank you very much :)

Comment: PHP's [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) might be useful.

Comment: http://php.net/substr, though explode() will be much easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php):

```
$mystring="|10|20|30|40";
$parts = explode('|', $mystring);
print_r($parts);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, If I run this code, I get: Array ( [0] => [1] => 10 [2] => 20 [3] => 30 [4] => 40 ) , but I need to get a specific part from the "|", so, I don't know how to get the specific part from a parameter

Comment: `$parts` is an [array](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php). You can access the elements by the numeric index.

Comment: thanks for the reply, yes, I had to make this: echo $parts[3]; thanks to all for the reply :)